# AmCharts Legend / Filter Configuration?

Tags: javascript, sass, visualization, amcharts

I'm working on a data intensive IOT project, and we are using many different AmCharts to display our data to the user. I just implemented a line chart with a legend and it's working very well. I have about 20 different assets being displayed, and they are different colors. The way AmCharts implements their legend is, when you click a color it is disabled.

**My question is can these be reversed easily? I want it so, when you click a assets color on the legend all the others on the chart are disabled, and the one you clicked is the only one being displayed.**

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-legend-to-show-only-one-graph-on-click/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`showItem`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#showItem) and [`hideItem`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#hideItem) events in the legend to force the clicked on marker to maintain its visibility by setting the graph's [`hidden`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmGraph#hidden) property to false and hide the other graphs by setting `hidden` to true:

```
// in makeChart:
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    // ...
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "showItem",
      "method": hideOthers
    }, {
      "event": "hideItem",
      "method": hideOthers
    }]
  },
// ...

function hideOthers(e) {
  var currentGraph = e.dataItem;
  currentGraph.hidden = false; //force clicked graph to stay visible
  e.chart.graphs.forEach(function(graph) {
    if (graph.id !== currentGraph.id) {
      graph.hidden = true;  //hide the others
    }
  });
  // update the chart with newly set hidden values
  e.chart.validateNow();
}
```

Demo below:

```js
function hideOthers(e) {
  var currentGraph = e.dataItem;
  currentGraph.hidden = false; //force clicked graph to stay visible
  e.chart.graphs.forEach(function(graph) {
    if (graph.id !== currentGraph.id) {
      graph.hidden = true;  //hide the others
    }
  });
  // update the chart with newly set hidden values
  e.chart.validateNow();
}

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "categoryField": "category",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start"
  },
  "trendLines": [],
  "graphs": [{
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "bullet": "round",
      "id": "AmGraph-1",
      "title": "graph 1",
      "valueField": "column-1"
    },
    {
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "bullet": "square",
      "id": "AmGraph-2",
      "title": "graph 2",
      "valueField": "column-2",
      "hidden": true
    }
  ],
  "guides": [],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
    "stackType": "regular",
    "title": "Axis title"
  }],
  "allLabels": [],
  "balloon": {},
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "showItem",
      "method": hideOthers
    }, {
      "event": "hideItem",
      "method": hideOthers
    }]
  },
  "titles": [{
    "id": "Title-1",
    "size": 15,
    "text": "Chart Title"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
      "category": "category 1",
      "column-1": 8,
      "column-2": 5
    },
    {
      "category": "category 2",
      "column-1": 6,
      "column-2": 7
    },
    {
      "category": "category 3",
      "column-1": 2,
      "column-2": 3
    },
    {
      "category": "category 4",
      "column-1": 1,
      "column-2": 3
    },
    {
      "category": "category 5",
      "column-1": 2,
      "column-2": 1
    },
    {
      "category": "category 6",
      "column-1": 3,
      "column-2": 2
    },
    {
      "category": "category 7",
      "column-1": 6,
      "column-2": 8
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background-color: #FFFFFF;"></div>
```

**Edit**

To make it so that clicking on the same marker toggles the visibility of the other charts back on, you can store a couple of flags in the chart instance itself through the event handler and use those flags to determine whether to hide all other charts or make them all visible:

```
function hideOthers(e) {
  var currentGraph = e.dataItem;
  var hidden = true;
  //check if we clicked on this graph before and if all the other graphs are visible.
  // if we clicked on this graph before and the other graphs are invisible,
  // make them visible, otherwise default to previous behavior
  if (e.chart.lastClicked == currentGraph.id && e.chart.allVisible == false) {
      hidden = false;
      e.chart.allVisible = true;
  }
  else {
    e.chart.allVisible = false;
  }
  e.chart.lastClicked = currentGraph.id; //keep track of the current one we clicked

  currentGraph.hidden = false; //force clicked graph to stay visible
  e.chart.graphs.forEach(function(graph) {
    if (graph.id !== currentGraph.id) {
      graph.hidden = hidden;  //set the other graph's visibility based on the rules above
    }
  });
  // update the chart with newly set hidden values
  e.chart.validateNow();
}

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // .. custom flags to make the above code work
  "lastClicked": null,
  "allVisible": true, //if you're only showing one graph by default, set this to false
  // ...
})
```

Demo:

```js
function hideOthers(e) {
  var currentGraph = e.dataItem;
  var hidden = true;
  //check if we clicked on this graph before and if all the other graphs are visible.
  // if we clicked on this graph before and the other graphs are invisible,
  // make them visible, otherwise default to previous behavior
  if (e.chart.lastClicked == currentGraph.id && e.chart.allVisible == false) {
      hidden = false;
      e.chart.allVisible = true;
  }
  else {
    e.chart.allVisible = false;
  }
  e.chart.lastClicked = currentGraph.id; //keep track of the current one we clicked
  
  currentGraph.hidden = false; //force clicked graph to stay visible
  e.chart.graphs.forEach(function(graph) {
    if (graph.id !== currentGraph.id) {
      graph.hidden = hidden;  //set the other graph's visibility based on the rules above
    }
  });
  // update the chart with newly set hidden values
  e.chart.validateData();
}

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "lastClicked": null,
  "allVisible": true, //if you're only showing one graph by default, set this to false
  "categoryField": "category",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start"
  },
  "trendLines": [],
  "graphs": [{
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "bullet": "round",
      "id": "AmGraph-1",
      "title": "graph 1",
      "valueField": "column-1"
    },
    {
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "bullet": "square",
      "id": "AmGraph-2",
      "title": "graph 2",
      "valueField": "column-2"
    }
  ],
  "guides": [],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
    //"includeHidden": true,
    "title": "Axis title"
  }],
  "allLabels": [],
  "balloon": {},
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "showItem",
      "method": hideOthers
    }, {
      "event": "hideItem",
      "method": hideOthers
    }]
  },
  "titles": [{
    "id": "Title-1",
    "size": 15,
    "text": "Chart Title"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
      "category": "category 1",
      "column-1": 8,
      "column-2": 5
    },
    {
      "category": "category 2",
      "column-1": 6,
      "column-2": 7
    },
    {
      "category": "category 3",
      "column-1": 2,
      "column-2": 3
    },
    {
      "category": "category 4",
      "column-1": 1,
      "column-2": 3
    },
    {
      "category": "category 5",
      "column-1": 2,
      "column-2": 1
    },
    {
      "category": "category 6",
      "column-1": 3,
      "column-2": 2
    },
    {
      "category": "category 7",
      "column-1": 6,
      "column-2": 8
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background-color: #FFFFFF;"></div>
```

Comment: That code worked perfectly. One last question. After the user clicks an item on the legend, and all the other items then are disabled, what's the easiest way to make it so if the user clicks that active item again all the other items become visible again? should I create another function like the one above but with the opposite functionality?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can set some custom flags to check what graph was last clicked and whether the other graphs are visible or not to determine whether you want to show or hide the other graphs.

Comment: Dude you rock, I appreciate the help so much. My project manager just told me our team has a paid AmCharts account for help, it's funny that I didn't even need to use it. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. AmCharts monitors StackOverflow as well (I happen to work for them), so we're happy to help whether it's on our support forum, here, email or even our Facebook page.

Comment: That's awesome! The code you posted is perfect, I was able to use it to get a working version for my project. The only issue I'm having is when I click one of the legend items, and the other items disappear, the chart is resizing, and is being cut off when I reenable the other items. If you look at your demo, it's happening there also. Is this a bug, or just a setting that can be configured?

Comment: It appears to be due to the stackType property in the valueAxis that got in from the snippet I based my answer on. If you're not using a stacked graph, remove it from the valueAxis config. You can optionally set [`includeHidden`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#includeHidden) to `true` in your valueAxis as well to keep the valueAxis min/max constant, which will also minimize the shifting and keep the scale constant if you want.

Comment: Hey, I was about to post this question in a new thread but I figured you would be the guy to talk to. All my different AmCharts are working great and we just pushed everything to QA. We noticed that on a few charts, the legends have this weird "Default" legend marker as the first item in the legend. Have you seen this happen before. Thanks For your time in advance.

Comment: Hm, can't say I've encountered this before. Post a new thread with code and some sample data that reproduces it and either myself or someone else will dive in and take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45042651/amcharts-bug-first-legend-item-default

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, I figured out the "Default" issue. Like I thought it wasn't on my end, it is a database issue. So our database engineers our going to take a look. Thanks Bud.

Comment: Ah, great. Glad you figured it out (sorry, was away from my desk at the time)

Comment: Hey man, I'm having another small issue with AmCharts. I created a new question, the link is below. I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379563/amcharts-gapperiod-issue

Comment: In 2020 and with amcharts4, how do we achieve the same? I run into errors with the hideOthers function call. Looks like the event structure has changed.

Comment: @blueren - yes, [amcharts4 is completely different with a totally different API](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/migrating-from-v3/#Not_an_upgrade). This warrants a new question instead of necroing an old v3 question from 2017.

Comment: @xorspark - I've created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60221701/1745073) on the back of this. If you could give some pointers to the back of this, it would be most helpful!