# AmCharts gapPeriod Issue

Tags: javascript, json, graph, amcharts

I'm having an issue with the AmCharts "gapPeriod" property. It says in the Docs, "Using this property you can specify when graph should display gap - if the time difference between data points is bigger than duration of minPeriod * gapPeriod, and connect property of a graph is set to false, graph will display gap."

I've tried many different values ("dapPeriod": 1, "dapPeriod": 0.1, "dapPeriod": .8,) I can't seem to get the line graph to display a gap between certain value markers. I've attached an image showing an example of my Line Chart, as you can see those long horizontal lines are extrapolation (false data). I want there to be a gap between markers, when there is not value to display. Any help will be much appreciated.

AmCharts Line Graph Example Image

[image]

Comment: Did you also set [`connect`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#connect) to false in your graph? Gaps won't work without it.

Comment: Yes I do have graph.connect = false; in my config. When that is active non of the markers are connected.

Comment: I got it to work, I had to use a value greater than 1.1 for some weird reason when 1 should have worked.

Comment: The documentation should probably be tweaked - the minPeriod * gapPeriod disconnect triggers when the period gap >= to that calculation. Assuming your categoryAxis' minPeriod is `DD`, setting gapPeriod to 1 basically means create a gap when the period is 1 day or more, which is why none of the points connect. This is why the default is 1.1 with the default `DD` minPeriod so that a single missed day will trigger the gap.